# how to create separated pages in same pdf document using play pdf

Tags: pdf, playframework, pdf-generation

I'm using play2-pdf to generate pdf in my application I created firstly the cover page but when I try to add the other pages its added in the same pdf page how can I create multiple pages in the same pdf document also I'm trying to add a footer to the my first page but still have the same problem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p.serif {
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        }
        p.sansserif {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is a test
        <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0;right:0;margin:24px;">by bSuccess</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For headers and footers, you can use css paged media module (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @@page {
                @@bottom-right {
                    content: "by bSuccess";
                    font-size: 14px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is a test
    </body>
</html>
```

For page breaks, you can use css page break properties (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @@page {
                @@bottom-right {
                    content: "by bSuccess";
                    font-size: 14px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>this is a test</div>
        <p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>
        <div>testing page break</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !!